# Python bs4 + lxml parsing table

Tags: python, data-structures, beautifulsoup, html-table, lxml

I want to parse table from this url - http://portal.ksada.org:8090/time-table/student?id=5598.
What i need to get at the end, is some kind of data structure. For example, what im tried to achive:

```
class Schedule():
   date='02.02.2022' # headdate class in html
   day='Ср' # headday class in html
   lessons=[['1 пара #span lesson', '09:00-10:35', 'КомпКн[Пз]', 'ауд. 304', 'Чайка Л.Е.'],
            [...],] # div with class lessons-1 or lessons-2
```

So with it i would know exactly hom many lessons some day will have. Maybe its not the best solution, and maybe thats why im stuck.
In general what i want is structurize all that stuff so i can get lessons for one day, week, and month. I tried many solutions, and just stuck there.
What i have for now is this code:

```
url = 'http://portal.ksada.org:8090/time-table/student?id='
id = 5598

def get_data(url, id):
    page = requests.get(url+id)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.select_one('table')
    items = []
    for tr in table.select('tr'):
        th_list = tr.select('th')
        td_list = tr.select('td')

        for th in th_list:
            print(th.text)
            for td in td_list:
                print(td.text.strip().replace('&nbsp', ''))
```

What im also tried is to find "distance" between each day, like so:

```
def get_data(url, id):
    page = requests.get(url+id)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    table = soup.find('table')
    tbody = table.find_all('tr')

    for i, t in enumerate(tbody):
            if t.find('th', class_='headday'):
                days.append(i)
```

And use it like:

```
for i, d in enumerate(days[:-1]):
        for t in tbody[days[i]:days[i+1]]:
```

I just dont know how to make this nicely somehow.

Comment: if you are open to pandas, you can read the table through `import pandas as pd` and then `table_list=pd.read_html('http://portal.ksada.org:8090/time-table/student?id=5598') table_list[0].head(20) # this is table structure `. You would still need to do some data wrangling though.

Comment: Thanks, thats already sounds good. But i didnt use pandas before, so cant even imagine how to wrap all this data. May you give me some suggestion?

Comment: Or how can i split all this data by week name? For your better understanding:
{'Monday':'Пн',
'Tuesday':'Вт',
'Wednesday':'Ср',
'Thursday':'Чт',
'Friday':'Пт',
'Saturday':'Сб',
'Sunday':'Нд'}
So in the top are dates as a header and all the rows that depends on that dates.

Comment: Thanks, Bohdan, this information helped to understand the days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you to get to the final solution.

```
#Import the library - pandas
import pandas as pd
```

```
table_list=pd.read_html('http://portal.ksada.org:8090/time-table/student?id=5598',attrs = {'id': 'timeTable'},flavor='lxml')
df = table_list[0].replace(r'&nbsp','NoValue', regex=True) # replace the value with NoValue, in case needed further
df_header=['Day','W1','W2','W3','W4','W5']
df.columns=df_header # logical header 
df.head(2) # this can be commented out as this is only for data viewing
```

As pandas read the first row as header, convert it to be as first row data.

```
#converting header to first row data
df_t=pd.DataFrame(columns=df_header, data=[table_list[0].columns.tolist()])
```

this is the final data frame that will be utilized for data needs.

```
df_final=df_t.append(df, ignore_index=True)
df_final.head(5) # # this can be commented out as this is only for data viewing
```

```
#setup for group weeks
week_days_notation=['Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб','Нд']
day_of_week=""
week_days=[]
for e in df_final['Day']:
    if e in week_days_notation:
        day_of_week=e
    week_days.append(day_of_week)
#week_days


# add the week_days to the dataframe
df_final.insert(0,'week_group',week_days)
df_final.head(2)

#group by week
df_final_grp=df_final.groupby('week_group')

# now can get week and  iterate in case needed
# give me only  'Wednesday':'Ср'
wed_classes=df_final_grp.get_group('Ср')
wed_classes.head(10)
```

**Additional use case: Move duration to the class which is missing it.**
To move class interval from `Day` to `W1`,`W2` or so can be done with apply and regex function.

```
def add_date_range(row,coln):
    if "NoValue" in row[coln]: # if NoValue in  any week day return spaces
        return " "
    
    day=row['Day']
    regexp = re.compile(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}(.*)\d{2}:\d{2})+')
    r_m=regexp.search(day) # find if 14:45 format is there in Day!
    if r_m: # if 14:45 format is there if True
        class_duration=r_m[0] # get duration 14:45  16:20 from Day
        
        r_w=regexp.search(row[coln]) # search time in Week
        if r_w:
            return row[coln]
        else:
            return f"{r_m[0]}  {row[coln]}" # append duration with original value
    else:
        return row[coln] # pass the original value

df_final['W1']=df_final.apply(add_date_range,args=("W1",),axis=1)
df_final['W2']=df_final.apply(add_date_range,args=("W2",),axis=1)
df_final['W3']=df_final.apply(add_date_range,args=("W3",),axis=1)
df_final['W4']=df_final.apply(add_date_range,args=("W4",),axis=1)
df_final['W5']=df_final.apply(add_date_range,args=("W5",),axis=1)
```

and then apply the group.

```
#group by week
df_final_grp=df_final.groupby('week_group')
```

[image]

Comment: Its just GREAT, simpleApp! Exactly what i wanted, i dont even know how to thank you for all this work! I am developing a telegram bot, and thats why I needed to parse all this data. I will definitely leave your contacts in the final script! And one more time, thank you very much!

Comment: glad it worked for you :) and you can select this as an answer and SO work is done! :)  all the best for your bot!